# How to change from false to true with checkbox input?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

If somebody can help me. I want to do next thing.With check box I want to choose which post to put on index page

This is my schema

```
var foodSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       title:String,
       image:String,
       text:String,
       video:String,
       checkBox:{type:Boolean, default:false},
       created:{type: Date, default:Date.now},
       comments:[{

                   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                   ref:"comment"
              }
    ]
});
```

This is my new.ejs file

````
     <spam class="hederSpam">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checked" value="true">
           post
    </spam>
```

here i wanna to display


``` <%newFood.forEach(function(check){ %>
      <%if(check.checkBox===true){%>
          <h3 class="indexh2"><%= check.title %></h3>
              <%=  check.checkBox%>
         <a href="/food/<%= check._id%> " >Read More</a>
  <% })%>
````

and in site.js file I trying to do this but every time gives me false..

```
   food.create(req.body.foodForm, function(err, postFood){
       var n = req.body.checked;
       if(err){
           console.log("err")
       }else{

           if( n == "true"){

               food.checkBox=true;
           }

              res.redirect("/food");


       }
   }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange piece of code:

```
console.log("err)
```

Also there should be space where I put underscore here:

```
 name="checked"_value="true"
```